# Why isnt the chosen device not opening in Jnetpcap (using eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, jpcap, jnetpcap

I am learning to use jnetpcap (on windows 8, 64bit). I installed Wincap first then set up the library in eclipse and ran this following example (without making any changes): http://jnetpcap.com/examples/classic.
It runs without any problems but once it chooses the device no packets are being sent and nothing is printing to console. I am running eclipse as admin (by right clicking). What else do I have to do for this example to work as its supposed to be. Please understand I am a java beginner. Here is what I have in my console(nothing prints after this):

```
Network devices found:
#0: \Device\NPF_{AFF01993-A0B1-44C1-815A-AB0327F5C126} [Qualcomm Atheros Ar81xx series     PCI-E Ethernet Controller]
#1: \Device\NPF_{75A1ADAE-EBAA-4162-9280-0E9CE654A2D4} [Microsoft]
#2: \Device\NPF_{6C11552A-C9A2-4DBC-947B-EEB9F198802C} [Microsoft]

Choosing 'Qualcomm Atheros Ar81xx series PCI-E Ethernet Controller' on your behalf:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the solution is not to let the code choose the device on my behalf and instead choose the device I want. That way I can test different devices.